# Flashing modal Window with WindowStyle=None

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, flashing

I have a WPF application where I show a dialog window which is modal and has its `WindowStyle` property set to `None` because I draw my own border/chrome and title bar.
Now I have the problem that I can't get that window to "flash" when the user clicks on the main window as it does with any other `WindowStyle`.

Is there a way to either show the "default shadow" with `WindowStyle="None"` so the flashing shadow is visible or can I somehow get the "flashing command" to implement the flashing on my own?

Comment: I think you might find the answer to your question in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158317/wpf-how-do-i-make-a-custom-modal-dialog-flash

Comment: @ekblom: Thanks for the Link - I think thats it. Did not find it as it does not mention `WindowStyle`...